# Obtain documentation for a module implementing the NSGA-II algorithm

Tags: python, module

I am attempting to use the implementation of the NSGA-II algorithm in this module https://github.com/wreszelewski/nsga2

**Question**

Where can I find documentation for this module?

Comment: Google is your friend [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nsga2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nsga2)

Comment: dear @jwpfox thanks for your guidance, but the site you addressed doesn't contain any document! it just have the module!

Comment: Is that the module you are trying to use? Since you didn't supply any guidance to us at all and didn't use the actual name of the module the first step was trying to find out what you were actually asking for help with.

Comment: @jwpfox i added this module to my python, and now i wanna an example that had been solve with this algorithm(nsgaii) to analyze module function.

Comment: Is the module I linked to the one you are trying to use? YES or NO - If NO what implementation of the algorithm are you trying to use?

Comment: @jwpfox yes its that

Comment: The documentation seems to be limited to the examples provided by the author. [https://github.com/wreszelewski/nsga2/tree/master/examples](https://github.com/wreszelewski/nsga2/tree/master/examples) Do they help you?

Comment: yes thanks @jwpfox

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems to be limited to the examples provided by the author. https://github.com/wreszelewski/nsga2/tree/master/examples

**Collecting metrics during evolution, then plotting hvr metric per generation**

```
from metrics.problems.zdt import ZDT3Metrics
from nsga2.evolution import Evolution
from nsga2.problems.zdt import ZDT
from nsga2.problems.zdt.zdt3_definitions import ZDT3Definitions
from plotter import Plotter

def print_generation(population, generation_num):
    print("Generation: {}".format(generation_num))

def print_metrics(population, generation_num):
    pareto_front = population.fronts[0]
    metrics = ZDT3Metrics()
    hv = metrics.HV(pareto_front)
    hvr = metrics.HVR(pareto_front)
    print("HV: {}".format(hv))
    print("HVR: {}".format(hvr))

collected_metrics = {}
def collect_metrics(population, generation_num):
    pareto_front = population.fronts[0]
    metrics = ZDT3Metrics()
    hv = metrics.HV(pareto_front)
    hvr = metrics.HVR(pareto_front)
    collected_metrics[generation_num] = hv, hvr

zdt_definitions = ZDT3Definitions()
plotter = Plotter(zdt_definitions)
problem = ZDT(zdt_definitions)
evolution = Evolution(problem, 200, 200)
evolution.register_on_new_generation(plotter.plot_population_best_front)
evolution.register_on_new_generation(print_generation)
evolution.register_on_new_generation(print_metrics)
evolution.register_on_new_generation(collect_metrics)
pareto_front = evolution.evolve()

plotter.plot_x_y(collected_metrics.keys(), map(lambda (hv, hvr): hvr, collected_metrics.values()), 'generation', 'HVR', 'HVR metric for ZDT3 problem', 'hvr-zdt3')
```

**Collecting metrics during evolution, then plotting hvr metric per generation**

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

class Plotter():
    def __init__(self, problem):
        self.directory = 'plots'
        self.problem = problem

    def plot_population_best_front(self, population, generation_number):
        if generation_number % 10 == 0:
            filename = "{}/generation{}.png".format(self.directory, str(generation_number))
            self.__create_directory_if_not_exists()
            computed_pareto_front = population.fronts[0]
            self.__plot_front(computed_pareto_front, filename)

    def plot_x_y(self, x, y, x_label, y_label, title, filename):
        filename = "{}/{}.png".format(self.directory, filename)
        self.__create_directory_if_not_exists()
        figure = pyplot.figure()
        axes = figure.add_subplot(111)
        axes.plot(x, y, 'r')
        axes.set_xlabel(x_label)
        axes.set_ylabel(y_label)
        axes.set_title(title)
        pyplot.savefig(filename)
        pyplot.close(figure)

    def __create_directory_if_not_exists(self):
        if not os.path.exists(self.directory):
            os.makedirs(self.directory)

    def __plot_front(self, front, filename):
        figure = pyplot.figure()
        axes = figure.add_subplot(111)

        computed_f1 = map(lambda individual: individual.objectives[0], front)
        computed_f2 = map(lambda individual: individual.objectives[1], front)
        axes.plot(computed_f1, computed_f2, 'g.')

        perfect_pareto_front_f1, perfect_pareto_front_f2 = self.problem.perfect_pareto_front()
        axes.plot(perfect_pareto_front_f1, perfect_pareto_front_f2, 'r.')

        axes.set_xlabel('f1')
        axes.set_ylabel('f2')
        axes.set_title('Computed Pareto front')
        pyplot.savefig(filename)
        pyplot.close(figure)
```

Do they help you?